# Codeigniter 4: Undefined type 'App\Controllers\Encryption' with Encryption::createKey()

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption, codeigniter-4

I am new to the Codeigniter 4 framework and I am trying to use the **[Encryption Service](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html#encryption-service)**.

I want to generate a key for encryption to store in the `app/Config/Encryption.php` file using the code:

`$key = Encryption::createKey();`

I am trying to create a key because the documentation says:

> The key should be as random as possible, and it must not be a regular
> text string, nor the output of a hashing function, etc. To create a
> proper key, you can use the Encryption library’s createKey() method.

But when I am trying out the code given in the above link, VSCode gives me an error saying:
**Undefined type 'App\Controllers\Encryption'.**

And Codeigniter gives me the error: **Class 'App\Controllers\Encryption' not found**.

How do I use the Encryption library and solve the above error and generate a key using Encryption::createKey()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pay attention to the namespaces. Use the full namespace:

```
$key = \CodeIgniter\Encryption\Encryption::createKey();
```

or use the `use` keyword to first "include" the class:

```
use CodeIgniter\Encryption\Encryption; // usually to be put at the top after the namespace `declaration`

...

$key = Encryption::createKey();
```

Comment: I tried both solutions. After implementing both solutions separately and together, I am getting this error: **Call to undefined method Config\Encryption::createKey()**. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi @HemantK. I have copy-pasted the wrong namespace from the documentation. Please see the updated my code.